# Chrome Developer Tools add a SINGLE file to workspace not folder

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, workspace

I'm doing some clean up work in the stylesheets. But there are some files that I don't want to touch by accident. So I don't want them to be editable. How can I add some files to the workspace but leave the rest of the files in the folder are not added.

Basically I want to achieve below;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DevTools technical writer here. It's not possible to choose which files are editable in Workspaces. The intended use of the feature is to persist any changes in a given directory to disk.

Maybe you'd prefer to use [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides)?

Also, a potential workaround could be to use `chmod` to disable write access on the files you don't want to touch...